# Module "django.core.mail.backends.console" does not define a "EmailBacked" attribute/class

Tags: django, django-urls, django-email

i am trying to code reset password of my web application now I am facing this error mentioned in tagline.
in my settings.py I have.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBacked'
```

my URLs are:

```
 path('password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='app/password_reset.html', form_class=MyPasswordResetForm), name='password_reset'),

 path('password-reset-done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='app/password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),

path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='app/password_reset_confirm.html', form_class=MySetPasswordForm), name='password_reset_confirm'),

 path('password-reset-complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='app/password_reset_complete.html'), name='password_reset_complete'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're omitting a letter, it should be`EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'`

Comment: yes you are right brother sorry for late response